# View generated source in IE 10

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-10, web-developer-toolbar

I'm trying to find a way to view the generated source using IE 10. With the Chrome dev tools and Firebug I can see the HTML source post JavaScript/AJAX operations but in IE 10 the view source command and dev tools both only show the downloaded source.

I'm building a single page javascript web app and am running into an issue in the generated source that only happens in IE. Using something like ChromeFrame or punting on the issue is **not** an option. I need to find and fix the root issue that is causing it in IE.

Do you all know of a different set of dev tools or a toolbar that is produced for IE 10 that will allow me to inspect this elusive generated html?

Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just press F12. If the DOM was manipulated via AJAX, you'll need to use the blue refresh button per the comments below.

Comment: Indeed, IE has had [developer tools since IE8](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/hh673541(v=vs.85).aspx).

Comment: er... I think you didn't read the question. The OP knows about F12/dev tools

Comment: For me the built-in F12 dev tools aren't showing updated source after the web app makes some data calls and appends the data to different elements. Am I doing something wrong when using them or is this behavior not normal?

Comment: Click the little blue "refresh" button in the F12 dev tools and it will update the HTML tree. It doesn't update in realtime like Chrome's does.

Comment: @ajp15243 IE 7 had Developer Toolbar (not necessarily natively)

Comment: @Ian I am aware, as I have had the misfortune of needing to use them. As you surmise they are not native and had to be installed separately, though IIRC they were still official tools from Microsoft.

Comment: @ajp15243 Haha so have I. Anyways, Firebug Lite isn't a bad tool for non-Firefox

Comment: Where is this little blue refresh button. I can't find it :(

Comment: what keystroke will expand all DOM nodes?

Answer (score 1):

I use alert(document.documentElement.outerHTML) to achieve this

Comment: Nice ! A solution that works the same in all current (and future) browsers. Might still be improved by writing it to a temporary file...

Comment: (Tiny) caveat: The starting `<!DOCTYPE html>` (or similar) tag will not be shown